# WebDriver Not returning inner text if input tag is not closed

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium Web Driver with java. I am not able to get inner text of an input tag which is not closed.

My HTML Code is like this:

```
<div id="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-0" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false"><p><input class="adjustRadioPosition" type="checkbox" onclick="showWidget(this);" name="gender" value="1">Male<br><input class="adjustRadioPosition" type="checkbox" onclick="showWidget(this);" name="gender" value="2">Female</p></div>
```

Now I want to fetch the inner text of input tag like Male or Female. As per my knowledge we can get inner text of any tag by using `getText()` if the tag is closed properly.

but in my scenario it is not closed so how can I fetch the text.

If any body know the solution for this scenario, please Provide the answer.

Comment: So you are saying that `driver.findElements(By.tagName("input")).get(0).getText()` returns null or fails on NPE?

Comment: getText() is returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like the text does not belong to "input" tag

execute 
$x('//*[contains(text(),"Male")]') 
in your browser javascript console - it should return the element that own this text

probably it will be "p" (that owns "Female" also, so for now I cant predict what "getText()" will return)

tag cannot be "not closed", since HTML should be well-formed (as any XML should)

Answer (score 2):

In cases where `getText()` returns **null** or an **empty string**,

I have found that

```
element.getAttribute("textContent")
```

returns the element's inner text.